# Blender bug with metric units

Tags: units

When I set Blender to metric units with scale '0.01' (centimetres) or any other scale, except '1', I meet a bug.

Sometimes, Blender displays some values in meters. If I click into value and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> immediately, it changes units to centimeters, although such operation should not change anything.

Proof: https://youtu.be/cJ-TfmF0PlI

**UPDATE**

It is a bug and it can be fixed.

One way is to adjust value after click. Initially it was `1.54844 m`. Once clicked, it became `1.54844`. Since absent units means cm, Blender should change the value to `154.844` immediately after click.

Other way is to retain unit in the window, but make it not selected, like windows do on file rename. Once I click `F2` on file with extension, it selects name but extension:

[image]

Comment: This isn't the place for filing bug reports. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports

Comment: Not everybody agree it is bug. So as me could not know it is bug until asked. Regard this as a question: is this a bug or feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Blender interprets input at the base unit measurement in that system. All you need to do is to input a **unit** as well as a quantity and this will work as expected (i.e. `12m` or `12cm` etc.)

As you have noted in your question, changing the **Scale** option changes what this base unit is. In your case the base unit is `cm`, so for any other unit of measure, you must input that unit after the numerical input.

Comment: Yes I understand this, but anyway it is a bug, since I didn't do anything while Blender changed the value.

Comment: No, it is completely expected. There has to be a default unit. All that is happening is that it is not carrying the units over when you edit them. You need to add them again. I agree that the feature you mentioned in your question should be added.

Comment: I don't edit anything. I just click and confirm. No editing. This is blender who change the value, not me. It treats it inconsistently.

Comment: You did not read my comment very carefully . . .

Comment: I have read that you suggested to enter the unit explicitly which is not contradicting the point that it is a bug.

Comment: This is not a bug. A bug is an unexpected exception or error in the code. Instead, this is a missing feature. Hopefully it is implemented at some point.

Comment: It is logical error in the code. When they are removing units from the field in editing mode, making it dimensionless, they forgot to multiply the value by the scale. They forgot explicit operation.

Comment: The code is doing exactly what the developers and anyone looking at the code would expect though. I do agree that it is handled improperly. I would also like to note that this is not a place to make bug reports, but for clear cut Q&A. Try reporting bugs to the tracker in future.