# Units and measurements and such 2.79 and 2.80

Tags: units

I am trying out both 2.79 and 2.80 and notice the behavior being the same.

I set the units to imperial and then changed the size of the default scene cube to something reasonable like 5cm. Then I applied the scale. My goal at this point was to make a radial array of 4 items, so I moved the cube 10cm on the x axis. Then I attempted to add an EMPTY cube which seems to come out huge.So I attempted to resize it by changing the dimensions, but it seems that I can put all sorts of numbers and units in the dimension boxes and in response blender just changes these values to some random number/unit combination even so far as up into miles and km.

It also seems odd that though I can choose units such as mm or inches, when looking at things the dimensions are shown in whatever blender seems to be in a whim to show, such as "thou" or "ft" with lots of decimal places.

Either:
 1. there is a bug, and it carries over between 2.79 and the current beta of 2.80, (my gut tells me this is unlikely)
or 
 2. I, personally, and not handling units correctly perhaps missing a step somewhere. (as a n00b this would be my guess, since it seems pretty complex of a program)

If I am just doing it wrong, can someone point me in the right direction for how to do it right?

Comment: is https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42254/blender-bug-with-metric-units?rq=1 helpful?

Comment: it matters which measurement system you use otherwise you might be confused by thing for example when using the imperial system default cube is 2 meters

Comment: the link is not related to this. In my case when I create the empty it came up really huge. So when i entered something like 2" or 5cm into one of the dimensions then leave the dimension to do so in the next one, it got changes to something like 6754miles or 37ft .. don't remember the specific numbers, but they were nonsense relative to what I entered, not a simply conversion factor issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see units other than 1 in 2.7 when setting the scene scale; I don't see mm or centimeters or meters (in the properties panel > scene tab)?

> *I can put all sorts of numbers and units in the dimension boxes and in
>   response blender just changes these values to some random number/unit
>   combination*

Blender adjusts from Meters to Centimeters to Millimeters as needed I think, eg.: when you scale from 99cm to 100cm it changes to 1m automatically (in the N panel).

> *Then I attempted to add an EMPTY cube which seems to come out huge.So
>   I attempted to resize it by changing the dimensions, but it seems that
>   I can put all sorts of numbers and units in the dimension boxes*

I don't see any dimensions boxes, just "scale" in the N properties panel, and "size" in the "empty" data tab of the properties panel.  I did notice the scale seems to be double what it should be, ie. mesh cube was 10cm but the empty cube was the same size, but says 5cm.  May be a bug or maybe a sort of radius measurment (measured from the origin)? Idk.
GL OP : )

Comment: I believe you may not be in Object Mode. The dimensions go away when you are in edit mode. Hit tab and you should see them.